# Basic apache rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2

Let's say I have exampleA.com and exampleB.com. If I wish to perform a rewrite on an Apache web server from websiteA.com to websiteB.com, as in when I type exampleA.com into a browser, it will retain the URL and show me the content loaded as if I was navigating to exampleB.com, how would I do this as a direct virtual host addition?

My research suggests something like:

```
RewriteRule /some/url(.*) http://exampleB.com/some/url$1 [P,L]
```

But what I am not familiar with is the relevance of the "/some/url" part, as I do not wish to only rewrite particular URIs, but the entire domain.

Similarly if I navigate to exampleA.com/test.htm, it should render whatever is at exampleB.com/test, with the browser saying "exampleA.com/test" the entire time.

Answer (score 2):

To have that rule apply to the entire domain, you'd want..

```
RewriteRule /(.*) http://exampleB.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Which is basically the same thing as:

```
ProxyPass / http://exampleB.com/
```

Keep in mind that there are a lot of things that could point the user's browser to the `exampleB` domain.  `ProxyPassReverse` would handle `30x` redirections:

```
ProxyPassReverse / http://exampleB.com/
```

But anything else in the content might be pointing to `exampleB.com`, including HTML content (which `mod_proxy_html` might help with), javascript, CSS, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

If you want to retain the original URL you need to actually proxy (look up ProxyPass) exampleb via examplea or use some sort of frames shenanigans.